# How do I provide stdin inputs from command line?

Tags: c, security, penetration-testing, stack-smash

I am trying to perform a buffer overflow attack on a program for a class assignment. Both the attack program as well as the vulnerable programme is written by me.

The vulnerable code uses `scanf` to read data from stdin.

`./vulnerable < malicious_payload_file.txt` works fine.
`more malicious_payload | ./vulnerable` and `echo JUNK_JUNK_JUNK_JUNK | ./vulnerable` also works as expected.

However, i would like to use the attack programme to keep supplying incrementally longer payloads till the programme crashes. So, I need to dynamically generate larger payloads of junks. I am using `system ("./vulnerable");` to repeatedly call and test for an abnormal exit.

How do I specify such a payload?

Is there a way to run `./vulnerable < malicious_payload_binary` or in some manner such that I do not have to put the malicious payload in a file, but can specify it in the command line?

Comment: I don't understand your question very well. The answer to the question in the last line could be: `echo "your payload goes here" | ./vulnerable`but you already know that. So, what exactly is the question?

Comment: @Susam Pal - I was looking for a more efficient approach than spawning a process for echo every time. each time I run `system` there shall be a bash process, echo process and vulnerable process.

Comment: As, I have mentioned in one of my comments below, `echo` is usually a shell-builtin. If so, it wouldn't spawn a new process. Run the command `type echo` to find out whether it is a shell-builtin or not.

Comment: You seem confused about the difference between *specify on the command line* and *supply on standard input*. Also, you are worrying about efficiency where it's really not important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to use the command line, you might try using `popen` instead of `system`:

```
FILE *fp = popen("./vulnerable", "w");
// write stuff to fp -- it goes to vulnerable's stdin
int exitcode = pclose(fp);
```

The exitcode you get from `pclose` is the same as what you would have got from `system`, had you used another process to create the data and piped it via the shell to ./vulnerable

Answer (score 9):

How about this?

```
echo "your payload goes here" | ./vulnerable
```

You can replace the `echo` command with any command that generates the input to ./vulnerable you want. One such example is a constant flow of junk as input, you can do this:

```
cat /dev/urandom | ./vulnerable
```

Comment: Do I not need to worry about the speed of execution if I pipe and spawn 2 processes?

Comment: I have no idea! I did not do it.

Comment: Thank you for attempting an answer. I tried `which echo` and got a `/usr/bin/echo'. Makes me doubt if echo is built into the shell. I know it is built into the command.com shell of DOS.

Comment: Don't try `which echo`. Try `type echo`.

Answer (score 0):

Try piping instead of redirecting:

```
./malicious_payload_binary | ./vulnerable
```

Comment: This would say `bash: malicious_payload_binary: command not found`

Comment: Maybe `./malicious_payload_binary | ./vulnerable`

Comment: @Grzegorz Szpetkowski - `malicious_payload_binary` would then have to be an binary file with execute permissions - which means an extra process. I am trying to avoid files totally and send payload via command line only - is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I think I finally understand your question (maybe), you want to read command line arguments? Something like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("the name of this program is %s\n", argv[0]);
    printf("%d command line arguments were provided\n", argc);
    printf("the input file is %s\n", argv[1]);
    // could do something like: fopen(argv[1]) here
    return 0;
}
```

If you compile it to a binary named `stdintest` and run it like so:

`./stdintest somefile.txt`

it will output:

```
the name of this program is ./stdintest
2 command line arguments were provided
the input file is somefile.txt
```

**OLD:**

As dolphy mentioned, just write to stdout in `malicious_payload_binary`, read from stdin in `vulnerable`, and connect them with a pipe: `./malicious_payload_binary | ./vulnerable`

Comment: I'm guessing I got downvoted because this isn't "specifying the payload at the command line", but it _is_ the answer to the **core** (poorly worded) question: "I need to dynamically generate larger payloads of junks".

Comment: I did not downvote anyone. I do understand that I was not able to express the question well and got too wordy. But the essence is in the title - 'how does one redirect stdin to take data specified in command line.'

Comment: You've still got my +1, and even more so now.